# auth token creation with LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle and Symfony 3.4

Tags: curl, symfony-3.4, symfony3.x, lexikjwtauthbundle, jwt

In my Symfony 3.4 Application I am trying to use LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle (v2.6.3).
I installed and configured it and created the needed keys like said on the github page:
https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#getting-started

They provide a test curl command there to check if it works:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost/api/login_check -d '{"username":"johndoe","password":"test"}'
```

This command allways returns a 302 and a small html-page redirecting to "../api/login".
This happens when entering falsy user data as well as when entering user credentials for an existing valid user. This also happens on all other pathes that start with "../api/".

What I expect "../api/login_check" to return is a token like

```
{
   "token" : "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXUyJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0MzQ3Mjc1MzYsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoia29ybGVvbiIsImlhdCI6IjE0MzQ2NDExMzYifQ.nh0L_wuJy6ZKIQWh6OrW5hdLkviTs1_bau2GqYdDCB0Yqy_RplkFghsuqMpsFls8zKEErdX5TYCOR7muX0aQvQxGQ4mpBkvMDhJ4-pE4ct2obeMTr_s4X8nC00rBYPofrOONUOR4utbzvbd4d2xT_tj4TdR_0tsr91Y7VskCRFnoXAnNT-qQb7ci7HIBTbutb9zVStOFejrb4aLbr7Fl4byeIEYgp2Gd7gY"
}
```

I am a bit stuck here on how to go on. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a syntax problem - this curl call works fine

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost/api/login_check -d "{\"username\":\"johndoe\",\"password\":\"test\"}"
```

Found it here (thanks to @ElGecko_76):
[Invalid JSON Message while using LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54959497/invalid-json-message-while-using-lexikjwtauthenticationbundle)